# How to find all descriptive statistics of a table in SQL server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there any code/query to find out all descriptive(mean,SD, min,max,sum,avg..) statistics  in a table, for example in a table I've 100 of column (variables) I wanted all numeric columns descriptive statistics .

Comment: If the problem is that writing it out by hand is too cumbersome, you can write a query that leverages `sys.columns` to generate the query parts per column.

Comment: Depending on your needs you have to play around with the system tables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-tables-transact-sql 
For example as @jeroenMonstert said above: `SYS.SCHEMAS`, `SYS.TABLES`, `SYS.COLUMNS`